# ajax поиск по кириллице перестал работать после переезда

Tags: javascript, ajax, opencart

После переезда на новый хостинг на сайте ajax поиск перестал искать по кириллице. Цифры и латиницу воспринимает нормально. Сайт на opencart.
Привожу код поиска:

```
function doLiveSearch( ev, keywords ) {

    if( ev.keyCode == 38 || ev.keyCode == 40 ) {
        return false;
    }   

    $('#livesearch_search_results').remove();
    updown = -1;

    if( keywords == '' || keywords.length < 3 ) {
        return false;
    }
    keywords = encodeURI(keywords);

    $.ajax({
        url: $('#hidden').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search/ajax&keyword=' + keywords,
        dataType: 'json',
        content: this,
        success: function(result) {
        if( result.length > 0 ) {
            var eList = document.createElement('ul');
            eList.id = 'livesearch_search_results';
            var eListElem;
            var eListElems;
            var eLink;
            for( var i in result ) {
                eListElem = document.createElement('li');
                eLink = document.createElement('a');
                $(function () {
                            eListElems = document.createElement('img');
                            eListElems.className='loading';
                            $(eListElems).load(function () {
                                $(this).show();
                            })

                    eListElems.src=result[i].image;
                    eLink.appendChild(eListElems);
                });
                eLink.appendChild( document.createTextNode(result[i].name) );
                if( typeof(result[i].href) != 'undefined' ) {
                    eLink.href = result[i].href;
                }
                else {
                    eLink.href = $('#hidden').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/product&product_id=' + result[i].product_id + '&keyword=' + keywords;
                }
                eListElem.appendChild(eLink);
                eList.appendChild(eListElem);
            }
            if( $('#livesearch_search_results').length > 0 ) {
                $('#livesearch_search_results').remove();
            }
            $('#search').append(eList);
        }
    }});

    return true;
}

function upDownEvent( ev ) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('livesearch_search_results');
    var fkey = $('#search').find('[name=search]').first();

    if( elem ) {
        var length = elem.childNodes.length - 1;

        if( updown != -1 && typeof(elem.childNodes[updown]) != 'undefined' ) {
            $(elem.childNodes[updown]).removeClass('highlighted');
        }

        // Up
        if( ev.keyCode == 38 ) {
            updown = ( updown > 0 ) ? --updown : updown;
        }
        else if( ev.keyCode == 40 ) {
            updown = ( updown < length ) ? ++updown : updown;
        }

        if( updown >= 0 && updown <= length ) {
            $(elem.childNodes[updown]).addClass('highlighted');

            var text = elem.childNodes[updown].childNodes[0].text;
            if( typeof(text) == 'undefined' ) {
                text = elem.childNodes[updown].childNodes[0].innerText;
            }

            $('#search').find('[name=search]').first().val( new String(text).replace(/(\s\(.*?\))$/, '') );
        }
    }

    return false;
}

var updown = -1;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').find('[name=search]').first().keyup(function(ev){
        doLiveSearch(ev, this.value);
    }).focus(function(ev){
        doLiveSearch(ev, this.value);
    }).keydown(function(ev){
        upDownEvent( ev );
    }).blur(function(){
        window.setTimeout("$('#livesearch_search_results').remove();updown=0;", 600);
    });
    $(document).bind('keydown', function(ev) {
        try {
            if( ev.keyCode == 13 && $('.highlighted').length > 0 ) {
                document.location.href = $('.highlighted').find('a').first().attr('href');
            }
        }
        catch(e) {}
    });
});
```

Comment: Запросы с кириллицей на сервер уходят? Какой результат?

Comment: Просто поиск по сайту работает и с кириллицей. Товары находятся. Кодировка базы utf-8, файлов тоже. В админке хостинга указана кодировка сайта utf-8.

Comment: Cобственно вопрос был про запросы ajax. Вероятней всего дело не в коде. Тем более если код работал и раньше и сейчас работает, но только с определенными видами символов. Могу предположить, что проблема из-за заголовков запроса/ответа. Но тут надо не код смотреть, а в Firebug.

Comment: Заголовок ответа Content-Type 
text/html; charset=UTF-8, но ответ пустой если искать кириллицу

Comment: Смотрите консоль браузера, там, наверняка, ошибки есть.

Comment: на старом хостинге Заголовок ответа Content-Type 
text/html

Comment: Кроме скрипта надо посмотреть еще контроллер модуля или какие изменения он вносит в контроллер стандартного поиска oc. Версии php на хостингах одинаковые?

Comment: Про версии ничего сказать не могу.

Comment: Проверьте, что у Вас в базе кодировка точно utf8_general_ci и покажите контроллер product_search из кэша Vqmod. В журнале ошибок OpenCart пусто?

Comment: Кодировка всех таблиц в базе  utf8_general_ci. Содержимое контроллера не могу сюда вставить. По длине символов не получается(

Comment: Скиньте то, что между: `public function ajax() {` и `echo json_encode( $data );` .

Comment: все равно много. может на мыло или в скайп?

Comment: a.g.efremov собака yandex , я чего так прицепился: я знаю что это за поиск и сам им пользовался, только он у Вас перепилен немного. Можно тогда и ссылку на сайт.

Comment: Я отправил письмо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому пригодится: проблема была в контроллере модуля живого поиска. Использовались функции strlen, strtolower, вместо utf8_strlen и utf8_strtolower (встроенных в OC хелперов для работы с юникодом).